# Visual Studio : know how to get gapless multiline comments?

Tags: visual-studio

In all the text editors I use, if you make your comments have a background color, there'll be no gaps between the coloring of each line.  So a 3 line comment is one big block of that background color and is simple and clean.  But in VS, they put a blank line or two between each commented line and thus it looks horrendous and clutters the screen.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks so much!

[what visualStudio does vs other coding apps:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjzQB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible.

It's a reasonable feature request however. I would suggest filing it via the "Suggest a Feature" action directly in Visual Studio. Be sure to include your screenshot.

[image]